# GET calls endpoint retuning empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get all active one to one and meeting calls. I am using communications/calls endpoint with a GET method, as per the documentation I can get the current calls using this API, I created Microsoft App as a bot however I get the following response with a field "value" as empty.

Response:
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/calls",
"value": []
}

Answer (score 0):

extended to a REST context, "the REST resource you requested doesn't exist." In your story, the login is fine, the search is performed, but it happens to have no results.